# Using text-overflow for an element with an inline-block

Tags: html, css

Trying to get `text-overflow: ellipsis` to work on an element that has an `inline-block` and a floated element to the right of it. I went ahead and created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GE2rX/3/) to show exactly how it's set up. But essentially there is a button that has a `float: right` that should *stop* the `span` with the `text-overflow`, but it's just pushing it down to the next line.

I know that if I set a `max-width`, it will work, but to me that would just be the quick solution, *not* the proper solution that truly fixes the issue. On the fiddle, set a `max-width: 150px` to the `.icon-list-inline .icon-text` to see what I'm talking about.

If you have any good solutions to this, *besides* saying set a `max-width`, which it seems is what most people recommend on similar S.O. questions, please let me know. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: FYI you have `float: right; display: inline-block` on the button - floats are always displayed as blocks so your `display` property has no effect.

Comment: That's fine. I just copied over bootstrap `.btn` CSS as to not write it all out. In my view, i just added the `.pull-right` on the button, which is why I added `float: right` to the `.btn` CSS. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just cut out the extra `<span>` tags that surround your text and stick the whole thing in another div.

```
<div class="block">
  <span class="icon-img">
    <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glyph_set/128/location_pin.png" />
  </span> 
  In vehicula mi at dolor volutpat vestibulum.
</div>
```

and change your CSS from defining `.icon-list-inline .icon-text` to this:

```
.icon-list-inline .block {
  margin-top: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qt4s8/

Comment: I like this solution. I assumed the trick was in the way the `HTML` was to be set up. You da man. I always want to avoid setting that `max-width`, because it's not practical on responsive sites. This is definitely a great workaround.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I think the important part is that your content is being displayed as `block` and not `inline-block`.

Comment: ^ Yea i agree. I have an `<h2>` tag with a `display: block` above this specific `<small>` tag that works perfectly.